# Странное поведение функции вывода в консоль в ядре ОС

Tags: c, указатели, kernel, ос, boot

Я создавал ядро для своей ос и столкнулся в проблемой при написании функции вывода на экран. Она работает только если заменить все указатели массивами
Использую FASM и MinGW GCC
Вот оригинальный код функции и точка входа (Взято с https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen):

```
void write_string( int colour, const char *string ) //указатель
{
    volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xb8000;
    while(*string) //указатель
    {
        *video++ = *string++; //указатель
        *video++ = colour;
    }
}

//extrn "_start"
//call _start 
void start(void)
{
    const char* string = "Hello"; //указатель
    write_string(0x0f, string);
}
```

*Этот код не выводит ничего, но когда я попробовал заменить все указатели массивами:*

```
void write_string(short colour, const char string[]) //массив
{
    volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xb8000;

    short count = 0;
    while(string[count]) //массив
    {
        *video++ = string[count]; //массив
        *video++ = colour;
        count++;
    }
}

void start(void)
{
    const char str[] = "Hello"; //массив
    write_string(0x0f, str);
}
```

*Этот код исправно выводит `"Hello"`*

Я конечно мог бы и оставить второй вариант, но раз повсюду в интернете пишут что нужно использовать указатели, боюсь что я в корне сделал что-то неправильно и в дальнейшем могут возникнуть непонятные ошибки.

**Почему так происходит, и что нужно сделать чтобы исправить это?**

**EDIT:** Почитав о разнице создания строк в массиве и с помощью указателя выяснилось, что используя массив строка хранится в стеке функции, а используя указатель строка создаётся в некотором месте в памяти. Так как у меня нет драйверов для работы с памятью, это возможно и является проблемой.

Comment: Хочется верить, что `short count;` на самом деле имеет вид `short count = 0;`.

Comment: А почему у вас и тип первого параметра поменялся с `int` на `short`?

Comment: @AnT во время поиска ошибок я поменял тип первого параметра, и в вопрос скопировал прямо из исходника. Но и с `int` вроде не работает

Comment: Код функции у вас на самом деле никак существенно не поменялся - в обоих случаях идет работа через указатель. А вот способ хранения передаваемой строки может быть действительно разным. И дело тут скорее не в массива/указателях, а в возможности прямого доступа к статическим данным (строковым литералам) в вашем окружении. Попробуйте первый вариант функции, но с `const char str[] = "Hello";` в `main`. Что получается?

Comment: @AnT может быть, хотя я вроде пробовал разные комбинации массивов и указателей. В любом случае я не могу в данный момент это проверить

Comment: Посмотрите на дизассемблер бинарника. Как в первом варианте инициализируется указатель `string`?

Comment: @AnT Сегодня проверил ваш способ и функция заработала, но мне до сих пор не понятно почему у меня не работает способ с вики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением следующих параметров компилятору: `-fno-stack-protector -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -mno-red-zone`
**EDIT:** Исправил ситуацию только параметр `-O3`, два других добавил по совету с форума.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется. что дело в приоритете операций. Если смотреть K&R, то там пишется, что операции

- '*' Взятие адреса
- '++' Инкремент

имеют одинаковый приоритет. Т.е., вроде бы '*' должна выполняться первой. Но там же написано, что эти операции выполняются справа налево! В таком варианте получается, что Вы пишите коды символов в байты цвета, а потом эти символы затираете цветом. Попробуйте написать в первом варианте функции так:

```
(*video)++ = *string++; //указатель
```

Может быть разные компиляторы по разному компилируют такое выражение.

Comment: Постфиксные операторы *всегда* имеют более высокий приоритет, что унарные. Поэтому ничего подобного в K&R написано быть не может. Никаких проблем с приоритетом в этом коде нет.

Comment: @AnT *Поэтому ничего подобного в K&R написано быть не может.* - Значит у меня что-то с глазами... Раздел 2.12 таблица 2.1 вторая строка: "!  ~ ++ -- + - * & (type) sizeof справа налево"

Comment: "Справа налево" в данном случае не имеет никакого отношения к порядку указания в таблице. "Справа налево" означает то, что *в конкретном выражении* операторы, стоящие *справа* от операнда, обладают большим приоритетом, чем операторы, стоящие *слева* от операнда. То есть это именно то, что я уже сказал выше: постфиксные операторы всегда имеют более высокий приоритет, чем префиксные (унарные). В выражении `*video++` приоритет операторов именно "справа налево": `++`  имеет более высокий приоритет, чем `*`. И никаких скобок не надо.

Comment: @AnT **И никаких скобок не надо.** Давайте посмотрим, что получается в таком варианте. *string* - это указатель на string[0]. Так ? Тогда (string++) - указатель на string[1]. Так?  Тогда операция присвоения *string++ = ... запишет СИМВОЛ в байт ЦВЕТА.  Так? Только это я их отел сказать.

Comment: Нет, конечно. Ничего подобного не произойдет. Откуда вы такое взяли? По определению, *постфиксная* форма инкремента всегда возвращает **оригинальное (исходное)** значение своего аргумента. В этом вся суть постфиксного инкремента (!). Результат выражения  `(string++)` - это указатель на `string[0]`, а не на `string[1]`. Никакой записи в байт цвета тут не получится.

Comment: @AnT **Никакой записи в байт цвета тут не получится.** - а что же происходит ? :-) На самом деле, надо спросить TS - помог ему мой совет, или  нет. И всё станет ясно.

Comment: ТС уже давно ответил на этот вопрос: первая версия функции прекрасно работает, если исходная строка хранится в локальной памяти. Т.е. если взять первую версию кода, но аргумент в функцию передавать так, как во второй версии кода, то все работает. Дело именно в этом, т.е. это уже ясно.

Comment: @AnT **это уже ясно** - т.е. Вы можете объяснить причину неадекватного поведения программы?

Comment: @Ant я нашёл ответ добавлением параметров gcc

Comment: @Sergey я нашёл ответ добавлением параметров gcc

Comment: @Jiftoo Поделитесь?  Мне это интересно!

Comment: @Sergey  Здравствуйте, исправил ошибку параметр `-O3`. Я уже описал это в ответе выше.